# Invertibility of a linear operator on a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inverse, compact-operators

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$, $T$ be a continuous linear operator of $H$, $r(T)=\sup_{||x||=1}|(Tx|x)|$ be the numerical radius of $T$, and $z\in \mathbb C$, such that $|z|<1$.
Assume that $r(T)\leqslant 1$.

Clearly $\ker (I-zT)=\{0\}$. So, if I could show that $T$ is compact then it would follow that $I-zT$ is invertible. So my questions are :

> 1. Is there an example of $T$ non compact ?
> 2. Is there an example of $T$ such that $I-zT$ is non surjective?

Comment: 1.: $T x = \frac12 x$.

Comment: Thanks for 1. What about 2?

Comment: As you observed, $I-zT$ is injective. If it is also surjective, then by Banach isomorphism=open mapping, it is boundedly invertible. And conversely. So you are asking: is there an example such that $z^{-1}$ belongs to the spectrum of $T$? In other terms, does there exist $T$ such that $r(T)\leq 1$ (numerical radius) but $\rho(T)>1$ (spectral radius).

Comment: So see [Theorem 5.1 here](http://www.math.msu.edu/~shapiro/Pubvit/Downloads/NumRangeNotes/numrange_notes.pdf) and Remark 5.2 if you want to go a bit further in the relation between the numerical range and the spectrum in $B(H)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes, any $T = \lambda\cdot I$ with $0 < \lvert\lambda \rvert < 1$ is a non-compact operator satisfying the requirements.

The answer to the second question is no, all such $I - z\cdot T$ are invertible.

First, by

$$\lvert \langle (I - z\cdot T)x \mid x\rangle\rvert = \lvert \lVert x\rVert^2 - z \langle Tx\mid x\rangle\rvert \geqslant (1 - \lvert z\rvert r(T)) > 0$$

for $\lVert x \rVert = 1$, it follows that $\lVert (I - z\cdot T) x\rVert \geqslant (1 - \lvert z\rvert r(T))\lVert x\rVert$, hence $\mathcal{R}(I - z\cdot T)$ is closed.

So either it is all of $H$, or $\mathcal{R}(I - z\cdot T)^\perp$ is nontrivial.
Suppose $y \in \mathcal{R}(I - z\cdot T)^\perp$. then, by the above computation,

$$0 = \lvert \langle (I - z\cdot T)y\mid y\rangle\rvert \geqslant \lVert y\rVert^2 (1 - \lvert z\rvert r(T))$$

and the second factor on the right is strictly positive, thus $\lVert y\rVert = 0$.